# PloneFormGen: Disable radio-button when a certain condition is met

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I want to create a dynamic form in a Plone 4.3 site with PloneFormGen 1.7.15. Dynamic means that I want to disable an option, when a certain number of participants have chosen this option.

- Is it possible the set the attribute "disabled" to a radio button? I have not found a way to do it manually.
- I was looking at the article [How can I generate a registration number in PloneFormGen, using a TALES Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271588/how-can-i-generate-a-registration-number-in-ploneformgen-using-a-tales-expressi) which show how to implement a counter. But I have no idea, how to actually change the radio button, when the condition is met. Any hints on that?

Comment: I don't have a real answer for you and maybe I'm offtopic, but if you are implementing an engine to subscribe to events you can evaluate the usage of http://plone.org/products/collective.signupsheet which user PloneFormGen but handle number of free slots.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer but you should be able to do a custom expression for a radio button vocabulary options. With this, you can check your property for tracking participants.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will look into collective signupsheet. This sounds good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used http://plone.org/products/collective.signupsheet for the form. It has the functionality to limit the number of registrants for an event.
The solution I thought of when asking the question became obsolete.